# What is "0is" notation in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax, rust-obsolete

As seen in this repository:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxRust/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L110

```
let gen = move |:| {
    let it = range(0is, 20is);
    //             ~~~  ~~~~
    let q   = Box::new(Decoupler::new(dtx.clone()));
    let mut map1 = Box::new(Map::new(|i : isize| {i * 10}));
    let mut map2 = Box::new(Map::new(|i : isize| {i + 2}));
    let mut iter = Box::new(IterPublisher::new(it));


    map2.subscribe(q);
    map1.subscribe(map2);
    iter.subscribe(map1);
};
```

(squiggly emphasis mine)

I'm trying to figure out what `is` after a numeral is. The Book says about literal suffixes only briefly:

> Note that all number literals except the byte literal allow a type suffix, such as 57u8, and _ as a visual separator, such as 1_000.
>
> — https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-types

And the compiler (1.53) only understands a set of specific suffixes, so I could not even get the original crate built on my machine:

```
invalid suffix `is`
help: the suffix must be one of the numeric types (`u32`, `isize`, `f32`, etc.)
```

Is it some sort of archaic syntax, or is it me missing something?

Comment: Since this code is from 2015, looks like it was indeed written for pre-1.0 Rust, with slightly different syntax. Not sure how to check this, however.

Comment: In addition to the `is` suffix not being a things in Rust 1.0, `|:|` isn't valid syntax, and `range` has been replaced by the `..` operator. Rust pre-1.0 changed regularly and doesn't compile anymore. The repository you were looking at is abandoned and not useful. Rust 1.0 and later will however still happily compile on the latest version of the compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the old, pre 1.0, times, integer suffixes were a little different.

Thanks to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150127084620/http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#integer-literals), we can take a peek to the past:

> There are 10 valid values for an integer suffix: \
>
> - The **`is`** and **`us`** suffixes give the literal type `isize` or `usize`, respectively.
> - Each of the signed and unsigned machine types `u8`, `i8`, `u16`, `i16`, `u32`, `i32`, `u64` and `i64` give the literal the corresponding machine type.

But in Rust 1.0 the first bullet went away and now you write `20isize` instead of `20is`.

Comment: the fact a signed size is a thing is one of my main nightmare.